# trueness of hadith about leaving what does not concern you; what is darussalam?

Tags: authenticity

there are hadiths that say [إِنَّ مِنْ حُسْنِ إِسْلاَمِ الْمَرْءِ تَرْكَهُ مَا لاَ يَعْنِيهِ](https://sunnah.com/search?q=%D8%A5%D9%90%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%20%D9%85%D9%90%D9%86%D9%92%20%D8%AD%D9%8F%D8%B3%D9%92%D9%86%D9%90%20%D8%A5%D9%90%D8%B3%D9%92%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%8E%D9%85%D9%90%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%92%D8%A1%D9%90%20%D8%AA%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%92%D9%83%D9%8E%D9%87%D9%8F%20%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%A7%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%8E%20%D9%8A%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%92%D9%86%D9%90%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%90) that mean "Surely, of the excellence of a person's Islam is that he leaves what does not concern him.". this hadith is marked " Da'if (Darussalam) ".

what is Darussalam? why/how they decided this hadith is weak (daif)?

are not there similar hadithes which are not weak?

this look like i like this hadith, but, actually, i think, how can this be true while quran and hadithes say that muslims should try to stop bad deeds? also, maybe this hadith easily can be used to say things like "do not learn that science, it does not concern you".

Comment: For "Darussalam" you should check the information on [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/about).

Comment: i think, this hadith is not very harmful. if somebody tries to shut someone's mouth using that hadith, or to refuse to answer questions, and try to show the asker like guilty, it is possible to answer this way: who decide what concerns me and what not? i decide it. (because i am a free person). so, this hadith is harmless in that regard. and, so, it should be interpreted as about leaving something by somebody that he thinks that does not concerns him.

Answer (score 2):

First of all different scholars when qualifying a hadith come to different conclusions about its authenticity, based on the data they have at hands.
Further a qualification for a specific version of a hadith might differ from a scholars overall position of the hadith content.

**Rough source analysis**

Secondly let's check sources that include this hadith:

On the authority of **'Ali ibn abi Talib**():

- Imam Malik's [Al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/516170) via the route:
  Malik -> ibn Shihaab a-Zuhri -> 'Ali ibn al-Hussain -> 'Ali ibn abi Talib.
- [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2318) via the route:
  Qutaybah -> Malik (from here same route of al-Muwatta).
  A-Tirmidhi commented this as a Mursal because **'Ali ibn al-Hussain never met his grandfather**. But a-Tirmidhi regarded this route as better than that of abu Salamah from abu Hurrairah.

On the authority of **abu Hurrairah**():

- [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3976) via the route:
  Hisham ibn 'Ammar -> Muhammad ibn Sho'aib ibn Shaboor -> al-Awza'iy -> Qurrah ibn Abdurrahman ibn Haywaiyl -> ibn Shihab az-Zuhri -> abu Salamah -> abu Hurrairah.
- [Jami' at Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2317) via the route: Ahmad ibn Nasr an-Naysaburi and others (more than one)-> abu Mushar  -> Isma'il ibn 'Abdullah ibn Sama'ah -> al-Awza'iy (Same route as ibn Majah).
- The "main" route from Sunan ibn Majah "al-Awzai'y -> ... -> abu Hurrairah" was also compiled by al-Bayhaqi in his as-Sunan al-Kubra (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31612/5079))and Shoa'ab al-Iman (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31612/10886)) and ibn Hebban in his Sahih (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31691/454))to name to rather prominent sources.

On the authority of **Zayd ibn Thabit**():

- Al-Mu'ajam as-Saghir (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13068/1025)) of imam at-Tabarani among other lesser known sources. In the named book via the route (the common route starts with the narrator marked in bold letters):
  Muhammad ibn 'Abdah al-Massisi (abu Bakr)  مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدَةَ الْمِصِّيصِيُّ أَبُو بَكْرٍ -> **Muhammad ibn Kathir ibn Marwan al-Filistyni** مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ كَثِيرِ بْنِ مَرْوَانَ الْفِلَسْطِينِيُّ -> 'Abdurrahman ibn abi az-Zinad عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ أَبِي الزِّنَادِ -> His father (abu az-Zinad) -> Khrajah ibn Zayd ibn Thabit -> His father.

On the authority of **al-Harith ibn Hisham**():

- Tareekh Dimashq (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/71/29621)) of ibn 'Asakir and elsewhere. Via the (common) route:
  Yahya ibn abi Unaysah يحيى بن أبي أنيسة -> ibn Shihab a-Zuhri الزهري -> 'Ali ibn al-Hussayn علي بن الحسين -> al-Harith ibn Hisham الحارث بن هشام

On the authority of **Anas ibn Mailk**():

- Via the route in a book of al-Hakim from Nishapur called Sualat as-Sijzy lil Hakim (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/535/19)):
  Abu al-'Abbas al-Assam ابو العباس الاصم -> Ahmad ibn Shayban ar-Ramly احمد بن شيبان الرملي -> Sufyan ibn 'Uyyanah سفيان بن عيينة  -> ibn Shihab a-Zuhri الزهري  -> Anas ibn Malik.

On the authority of **Usamah ibn Zayd**():

- In a book called al-Intikhab الانتخاب of abu Tahir a-Silafi أبو طاهر السِّلَفي (the book doesn't exist in a printed version). Via the route:
  'Umar ibn Qays عمر بن قيس -> ibn Shihab a-Zuhri الزهري -> 'Ali ibn al-Hussayn -> Amr ibn 'Uthman عمرو بن عثمان -> Usamah ibn Zayd.

On the authority of **abu Bakr**():

- in the book Ma'arift a-Shabah of abu Nu'aym (see [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/10490/5259)). Via the route:
  Malik ibn 'Atiyyah مالك بن عطية -> His father -> Abu Rafi'ah al-Fahmi أبي رفاعة الفهمي -> abu Bakr.

**Discussion of the routes and sources reliability**

The most reliable routes however are the first two: 'Ali ibn al-Hussayn (from His father) from His grandfather and that of abu Hurrairah.  And almost all scholars agree that this hadith is mursal (means a narrator is left out unnamed). Some regard the route
Qurrah -> al-Awza'iy -> ibn Shihab -> abu Salamah -> abu Hurrairah
as connected however Qurrah is not a much reliable narrator.

For further information and more details on the sources refer to my main reference for takhreej of the hadith ([here](https://sotor.com/%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AC_%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB:_%D9%85%D9%86_%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86_%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A1_%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%83%D9%87_%D9%85%D8%A7_%D9%84%D8%A7_%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%87) in Arabic).

If my interpretation of al-Harith ibn Hisham is correct here again 'Ali ibn al-Hussayn can hardly have met him because he died the the plague of 'Amwaas which happened around 18 a.H..

**An overall estimation**

As you may see from this rather rough and superficial check all variations of this hadith have some issues. So even if one could come to an overall qualification that it is at least hassan lighayrih (due to backup elsewhere) almost all of the versions could be regarded as da'if by themselves.
Some scholars consider it hassan by itself. Note that the acceptance of mursal hadith was already a matter of discussion in the first 3 centuries.

Sheikh al-Albani when asked about the hadith (not a specific variation or compilation) answered that he regarded it as sahih (My own understanding: in his terminology hassan and sahih are rather similar level) -see [here](https://www.al-albany.com/audios/content/4733/%D9%85%D8%A7-%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A1-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%83%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%84%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%87-%D9%88-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB) in Arabic-.

**High acceptance of scholars**

This hadith appears in the 40-Hadith of imam an-Nawawi. This alone should tell that scholars consider this hadith's content as an important statement and teaching of Islam.

Some scholars counted it as a third or fourth of the knowledge (of Islam).

It was quoted that ['Abdullah ibn abi Zayd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abi_Zayd_al-Qayrawani) said:
 <sup>heer and in the following I'll be translating from Arabic text, as tehse translations are of my own take them caerfully</sup>

> جِمَاع آدَاب الْخَيْر يَتَفَرَّع مِنْ أَرْبَعَة أَحَادِيث
> The collection of good manners is branched out from four ahadith:
> (Source [1](http://www.saaid.net/daeyat/zadalmaad/24.htm), [2](http://www.saaid.net/Doat/alnaim/21.htm))

And he counted beside the hadith discussed here the following three ahadith among them:

- > "Whoever believes in Allah and the Last Day should talk what is good or keep quiet, ... "(See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6475))
- > "Do not become angry and furious." ... (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6116))
- > ""None of you will have faith till he wishes for his (Muslim) brother what he likes for himself."" (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukahri](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:13))

Abu Dawod the author of the Sunan also wrote or was quoted to having said or written the following:

> كَتَبْت عَنْ رَسُول اللَّه صلى الله عليه وسلم خَمْسمِائَةِ أَلْف حَدِيث، الثَّابِت مِنْهَا أَرْبَعَة آلاف حَدِيث, وَهِيَ تَرْجِع إِلَى أَرْبَعَة أَحَادِيث
> I wrote on the authority of the Messenger of Allah, Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him, five hundred thousand ahadith, of which the established (sane) ones are four thousand, and they are traced back to four ahadith.
>  <sup>Note that I couldn't find some of this quotes in his Sunan * or in a different wording **, my references for these ones will link to a corresponding hadith from the 40 hadith of imam an-Nawawi</sup>

1. > قَوْله عَلَيْهِ الصَّلاة وَالسَّلام (إِنَّمَا الأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ)
   > His Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him statement "[Actions are to be judged only by intentions](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2201)".
2. > وَقَوْله (مِنْ حُسْنِ إِسْلامِ الْمَرْءِ تَرْكُهُ مَا لا يَعْنِيهِ)
   > His statement "Part of the excellence of a man's Islam is that he leaves what does not concern him.*"
3. > وَقَوْله (الْحَلالُ بَيِّنٌ وَالْحَرَامُ بَيِّنٌ)
   > And his statement "[What is lawful is clear and what is unlawful is clear](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3329)".
4. > وَقَوْله (لا يَكُون الْمَرْء مُؤْمِنًا حَتَّى يَرْضَى لأَخِيهِ مَا يَرْضَى لِنَفْسِهِ)
   > And his statement "[A person is not a believer until he consents for his brother what he would like for himself.](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40:13)**"
   > وَرُوِيَ مَكَان هَذَا (اِزْهَدْ فِي الدُّنْيَا يُحِبَّك اللَّهُ)
   > And instead of this was also narrated:"[Renounce the world and Allah will love you](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40:31)"

> (Sources [1](http://www.saaid.net/Doat/alnaim/21.htm) & [2](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/281048/%D8%AD%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87%D8%AC-%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B3%D9%86%D9%86%D9%87-%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB%D9%87))

Among the verses that support the meaning of this hadith you may often find quoted:

- > No good is there in much of their private conversation, except for those who enjoin charity or that which is right or conciliation between people. And whoever does that seeking means to the approval of Allah - then We are going to give him a great reward. ([4:114](https://legacy.quran.com/4/114))

Comment: you have mentioned chains from 7 first transmitters, but you comment only about 3 of them, and you said "As you may see ... all variations of this hadith have some issues". no, i do not see. and you said "almost all of the versions could be regarded as da'if by themselves". where can i see? ok, i looked at one of the al-maktaba links through google translate and i have seen something like that...

Comment: you quoted 3 hadiths mentioned by 'Abdullah ibn abi Zayd , but what is logic connection with the hadith i asked? seems none of them logically 100% (inevitably) brings (gives) the meaning in the hadith i asked.

Comment: about the idea of abu dawud, as quoted here, it is not proof for the hadith, but rather it means that that hadith among 4 hadiths is like a general idea that corresponds with many other hadiths. just corresponding is not yet logical causing this hadith by some that many hadiths.

Comment: the ayah 4.144 is only about private conversation, while saying about something that can be counted by somebody as "does not concern him" can be done [quite] publicly.

Comment: Should I really answer all these wrong comments? Sorry but either you are blind or unable to understand. I've counted 7 Sahabah whom transmitted a hadith on each of them I've pointed at sources and linked those which exist, And I'm saying on each of them, not 1 not 2 nor 3! If you don't see you are blind or unable to read a text. The same shoudl apply for the rest of your senseless comments. Once you stop discussing without having a hint of an idea what the topic is about we can check further.

Comment: do you think all of this comments wrong?

Comment: 2 first transmitters: " ... 'Ali ibn al-Hussayn (from His father) from His grandfather and that of abu Hurrairah ... Some regard the route Qurrah -> al-Awza'iy -> ibn Shihab -> abu Salamah -> abu Hurrairah as connected however Qurrah is not a much reliable narrator. ".
1 first transmitter: "If my interpretation of al-Harith ibn Hisham is correct here again 'Ali ibn al-Hussayn can hardly have met him ..." .
so, you wrote about 3 of them here in english, others maybe written by the links in arabic.

Comment: "The same shoudl apply for the rest of your senseless comments. Once you stop discussing without having a hint of an idea what the topic is about we can check further." - what i did not understand correctly? first you said about isnad, than you started to say about content, meaning. i answered that there is no strong logic proof yet that the idea of the hadith comes from other hadiths and ayats. so, it has its own independent meaning. so, trust to it has to rely on its isnad.

Comment: If you want to discuss open a chat room. I've nowhere addressed the meaning of the hadith. I've tried to analyse it's sources (isnad) and gave here a rough summary of it. Whether you can read Arabic or not is not my problem nor is the goal of answering here to translate books. As that what I'm referring to is written or at least summarized here.